# how to make it so that after start the first timer, when starting another, instead of starting a new one, it shows how much time is left in the first

Tags: python, aiogram

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import Command, CommandObject, CommandStart


bot = Bot('TOKEN')
dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message(Command('start'))
async def start(message:Message):
    await message.answer(f'Hello, {message.from_user.first_name}! comands:\n/go')


@dp.message(Command('go'))
async def vyl(message:Message):
    await message.answer(f'{message.from_user.first_name},list of commands: /go1 /go2 /go3 /go4 /go5)')


@dp.message(Command('go1'))
async def vyl1(message:Message):
    time_vyl1 = int(14400)    vylt1 = await message.answer(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, you're go to 1 ({time_vyl1}sec)')
    for timev1 in range (time_vyl1-60, -1, -60):
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        await vylt1.edit_text(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, you're go to 1 ({timev1}sec)')


@dp.message(Command('go2'))
async def vyl2(message:Message):
    time_vyl2 = int(21600)
    vyl2 = await message.answer(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, you're go to 2 ({time_vyl2}sec)')
    for timev2 in range (time_vyl2-60, -1, -60):
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        await vyl2.edit_text(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, you're go to 2 ({timev2}sec)')


@dp.message(Command('go3'))
async def vyl3(message:Message):
    time_vyl3 = int(36000)
    vyl3 = await message.answer(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, you're go to 3 ({time_vyl3}sec)')
    for timev3 in range (time_vyl3-60, -1, -60):
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        await vyl3.edit_text(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, you're go to 3 ({timev3}sec)')


@dp.message(Command('go4'))
async def vyl4(message:Message):
    time_vyl4 = int(50400)
    vyl4 = await message.answer(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, you're go to 4 ({time_vyl4}sec)')
    for timev4 in range (time_vyl4-60, -1, -60):
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        await vyl4.edit_text(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, you're go to 4 ({timev4}sec)')


@dp.message(Command('go5'))
async def vyl5(message:Message):
    time_vyl5 = int(72000)
    vyl5 = await message.answer(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, you're go to 5 ({timev5}sec')
    for timev5 in range (time_vyl5-60, -1, -60):
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        await vyl5.edit_text(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, you're go to 5 ({timev5}sec')


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I didn't try anything because I knew it probably wouldn't help